# How does CSS Media Query work exactly?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Let's say I have 2 different CSS files (desktop.css and ipad.css) being applied to the same html page.

I have some pseudo div defined as follows (**in desktop.css**)

```
div.someClass{float:left;overflow:hidden;height:100px}
```

Now at say lower screen size (user resizes browser to iPad size) and iPad.css gets applied.
So my question is, will the effect of properties defined in desktop.css still remain OR is it completely wiped out and only ipad.css properties get applied..

Like in ipad.css, if I want to have overflow:visible (i.e. default overflow value), do I need to explicityly specify that OR if I just define as follows in **ipad.css**

```
div.someClass{float:left;height:100px}
```

it would automatically apply the default overflow:visible value to the div ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@testndtv; you have to write `overflow:visible` in your `ipad.css` because `media query`  only detect the `screen resolution` & then active the `css`  according to `screen resolution`. That's why we can only `override` our `ipad.css` property from the activate one.

So, for `ipad.css` write like this:

```
div.someClass{float:left;overflow:visible;height:100px}
```

Comment: So in effect r u saying that if we not not explicity specify overflow:visible in ipad.css and in case we resize from desktop to ipad.css, the div would still have the overrflow effect or property coming from desktop.css as hidden ?

Answer (score 1):

The **C** in CSS is for *Cascading*. The `ipad.css` styles (provided they are loaded after and have higher specificity) will have higher precedence and will be applied.

Any properties which are not defined in `ipad.css` but are in `desktop.css` for the same element (provided you load the `desktop.css` first) will default to the rules set in `desktop.css`.

Answer (score 0):

This is dependend on how you place your queries. You can do both.

Comment: if one css is  included only when display size is >1024 and another ONLY when the display size is <1024 then you have always one single style sheets.